# Clear error after removing .frm file

Tags: mysql

I have accidentally deleted a .frm file for a test table. The problem is that I can not drop this table and remove it from information_schema.

```
select * from information_schema.tables where table_name like 'testtesttest';
+---------------+--------------+--------------+------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME   | TABLE_TYPE | ENGINE | VERSION | ROW_FORMAT | TABLE_ROWS | AVG_ROW_LENGTH | DATA_LENGTH | MAX_DATA_LENGTH | INDEX_LENGTH | DATA_FREE | AUTO_INCREMENT | CREATE_TIME | UPDATE_TIME | CHECK_TIME | TABLE_COLLATION | CHECKSUM | CREATE_OPTIONS | TABLE_COMMENT                                            |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| def           | report       | testtesttest | BASE TABLE | NULL   |    NULL | NULL       |       NULL |           NULL |        NULL |            NULL |         NULL |      NULL |           NULL | NULL        | NULL        | NULL       | NULL            |     NULL | NULL           | Can't find file: './report/testtesttest.frm' (errno: 13) |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+----------------------------------------------------------+

drop table report.testtesttest;
ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'testtesttest'
```

Is there a way to tell mysql that such a table no longer exists?

Comment: Which engine did you use?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like that the following steps help:

1. touch /var/lib/mysql/report/testtesttest.{frm,ibd}
2. chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/report/testtesttest.frm
3. restart mysql
4. drop table report.testtesttest;